# Access Excel webquery file in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, excel, excel-web-query, excel-automation, vba

I have created a webquery in excel which fetches data from the webpage in Excel file. Is there anyway i can access the same webquery in C#. I hope it makes sense. Need some valuable suggestions with the coding.

Comment: you want to access the excel webquery and use it in c#? why not just "rewrite" the webquery in c#?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to initiate and rewrite it in C#. Would you please give me some idea with the coding...

Comment: you might find something here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N

Comment: isn't the Excel Webquery part of the Workbook QueryTables collection? If so, you could access it from c# using Automation

Answer (score 0):

to see how to access a web querytable through VBA in Excel, take a look at the

[MSDN Library: QueryTables/Webtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215967%28v=office.11%29.aspx) documentation

this will give you the objects that you would work with in c#

for example, a Webquery is stored in a **Querytable object** in a worksheet in a workbook in the Excel application.

The webquery has a connection object which shows the URL, and a WebTables property determines which tables are brought in from the web page to your worksheet.

So now you just have to do some reading, and write some c# code